# Symfony - softdeleteable delete the entity but let me query it after

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com, soft-delete

I want to implement `softdelete` in my symfony application.

I'm using `Symfony5` and `ApiPlatform` for the back.

I've run the following command to install the bundle

```
composer require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle
```

Installation worked as `composer.json` now has :

```
"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.5",
```

So I've updated my `stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml` file as follow:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            softdeleteable: true
```

I added the `@Gedmo` annotation to the entity I want to apply `softdeleteable` on

Added the `deletedAt` field, generated the migration and reload the database.

Here is my `Entity.php` file:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false, hardDelete=false)
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EntityRepository::class)
 */
class Entity
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"entity:read", "entity:list", "user:read", "user:list"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"entity:write", "entity:read", "entity:list"})
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;
}
```

I've also written a simple test to see if the feature was working:

```
public function testRoleAdminCanSoftDeleteEntity(): void
   {
        $this->buildEntityManager();

        $res = $this->buildDeleteRequest(
            GenericRoutes::ROUTE.'/11',
            GenericCredentials::ADMIN_CREDENTIALS
        );

        $entity = $this->em->getRepository(Entity::class)->findEntityByEntityField(json_decode(GenericCredentials::CREDENTIALS)->email);

        $this->assertNull($entity);

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(204);

    }
```

I receive a `204` but the specialist isn't empty.

I've also used the swagger to manually delete the `entity/{id}` I wanted to remove.

I also receive a `204` and then can query the same `entity/{id}` right after.

I've verified in the database and the `deleted_at` field is updated to the moment I ran the `DELETE` request.

Does anyone has any idea why I still can query this `user` which I just soft deleted ?

Comment: Did you configured filters as it is described in the docs? http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/softdeleteable.html

Comment: I missed that part! Thanks! Would you know in which file I'm supposed to implement those filters ? I don't see indications on that in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, regarding to my comment.

You just need to configure filter in the doctrine config, smth like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      ...
    orm:
      ...
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```

But in my opinion, it would be much more easy to not using this extension, it is just one more dependency in your project, and just create yourself nullable `deletedAt` property to the entity and set it to `DateTime('now')` on delete, and then you can get not deleted entries from the repo just adding one more criteria to findBy - `'deletedAt' => null`

Comment: This configuration is what was missing and finally make things work, thank you!
Yes but having lots of entity linked to this one, I think would just be adding a lot of conditions at different places that would complicate the code more than it would with this dependency.
Nice workaround for smaller project though!

Comment: Glad to be helpful!